# How can I ask a user to select from some different modes for an application?

Tags: grammar

I have a mobile application that has three modes: Learn, Practice and Quiz.

Above the buttons that I would like to write a message that would in the most friendly way ask the user to pick one. What I have thought of so far is:

"Choose one of the modes below to tailor your learning experience"

But I am not sure about the way I have used the word "tailor" and also if this is the best way to tell the user to pick one of the modes.

Does anyone have any advice / suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please choose one of the following modes:
>
> Learn; Practice; Quiz

This is a very pleasant and polite way of asking them to choose.

The three choices you've presented are not really a customization of the experience.  Rather, they're three separate stages of the process.  First you learn, then you practice, then you take the quiz to show what you've learned.

On the other hand, if you were offering different teaching methods, you could say:

> Please choose the mode that best suits your learning style:
>
> Lecture, Question and Answer, Group Discussion

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives for **tailor**:

**Customise**

**Enhance**

**Personalise**

**Craft**

**Mould**

**Shape**

I favour the last three here. They give the impression that it is the user who is primarily responsible for setting their learning experience as opposed to an algorithm. And if there's one thing people love, it's the feeling of accomplishment, of making something with your own two hands (or at least they love the idea of it.)